# extracting positions from list based on values in items

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am relatively new to using python. I am trying to take a standard file format and eventually break it out into smaller files based on a certain identifier that appears on a line.

I have so far been able to take the file, open it to read and write, then broken out each line into a list item. Now I am trying to locate each list item position that starts with '03'. Everything from one '03' list position to another is what will eventually be a separate file. I am stuck in trying to extract the list positions where the list value contains '03'. I have tried using:

```
for value in acct_locate:
    if value == '03':
        locations.append(acct_locate.index(value))
```

This seems to be returning nothing, and I have tried some other versions of `enumerate()` and `index()`.

Currently here is my code that I am working with:

```
import re
#need to look for file name
filename = 'examplebai2.txt'

#this list will store all locations where three record shows up
acct_locate = []
locations = []
acct_listing = []

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    line = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
    for x in line:
        #locate all instances of locations starting with '03'
        look = re.findall('^03', x)
        acct_locate.append(look)
        #add those instances to a new list
    a = [i for i,x in enumerate(acct_locate) if x == '03']
    for value in a:
        print(value)
        locations.append(acct_locate.index(value))
    for y in line:
        namelist = re.findall('^03, (.*),', y)
        if len(namelist) > 0:
            acct_listing.append(namelist)
```

Running the above code will return nothing to the `locations` list that I am using to gather all of the locations.

Here is a skeleton of the file I am trying to manipulate.

```
01, Testfile
02, Grouptest
03, 11111111
16
88
49
03, 22222222,
16
88
49
03, 33333333,
16
88
49
03, 44444444,
16
88
49
98, Grouptestclose
99, Testfileclose
```

From this file I would want to end with four separate files that contain from one `03` record up to the next `03` record.

Comment: Show me some examples of lines in the file.

Comment: @satoru I updated the above description with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to know the positions of your special characters you could do:

```
with open('examplebai2.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')

data = data.split('03')
```

*explanation*: the first two statements read the file, remove all newline characters and put the result into a single string "data". The last statement splits the string on occurences of your "special character" '03', returning a list of strings where each element is a piece between two '03'.

**EDIT:**

Given the example data above, you could try to loop over the file and put the read data into a buffer. Every time you find a '03', empty the buffer into a new file. Example:

```
buffer = ""
new_file_counter = 0
with open(filename,'r+') as file:
    ## loop over lines
    for x in file:
        if x.split(',')[0] == '03':
            with open('out_file_{}'.format(new_file_counter)) as out:
                out.write(buffer)
                buffer = ""
                new_file_counter = 0
        buffer += x
```

Comment: I want to keep the the `03`, not just split it out. But the `03` would act as the indicator where I would want to start a new file. I added an example skeleton file above. I would want to create a file that goes from the first instance of the `03` record through the `49`. Then another file from the next grouping like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "locate all instances of locations starting with '03'", you should check `x.startswith("03")` instead of `x == "03"`.